# HttpsUrlConnections in Java Web Start app do not trust SSL certifiates added to Java Control Panel

Tags: java, https, jersey, jax-rs, java-web-start

The short version: Is there a way to make HttpsUrlConnections started inside a Java Web Start app trust the certificates installed in the Java Control Panel, or is there another user-friendly way (not involving the command line) to add certain certificates to the trust store used by such connections?

Our Java Web Start application accesses several web services (via JAX-RS/Jersey in standard configuration, which ultimately uses the JWS-specific implementation of HttpsUrlConnection). Occasionally these will throw SSL certificate validation errors due to untrusted certificates:

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

These can occur for several legitimate reasons:

- In our test environments, the site certificates are issued by our internal CA which is not trusted by the JRE by default
- Some of our users have "SSL terminating" proxies which is a fancy name for a web proxy that decrypts SSL traffic and forwards it on using a different certificate. This is indistinguishable from a man-in-the-middle attack from the app's point of view.
- After upgrading servers in production we test the app by launching it from the individual servers before adding them to the load balancer; the certs for these servers are also signed by our internal CA.

At the moment we have code that picks up on these errors, shows the user a suitably stern-worded warning and, if the user wishes to proceed, installs an "accept-all" default trust manager and hostname verifier to HttpsUrlConnection to bypass SSL validation entirely, as widely documented elsewhere. This is a cumbersome solution, it is hard to maintain, it appears on every execution of the app, it will mask other errors (we connect to more than one site) and feels like re-inventing the wheel.

An alternative is to use keytool to add the untrusted CA certificate to the JVM's trust store. This is not a very user-friendly solution as it involves a lot of command-line hackery and will be wiped out after every JRE upgrade.

I would expect adding these certificates to the Java control panel would also achieve the same thing but it seemingly does not; although it gets rid of the Java Web Start warnings when installing and launching the app, HttpsUrlConnections made from inside the app still do not trust these certificates, leading to the errors and home-grown override described above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that JAX-RS does not use the default `SSLContext` and `HostnameVerifier`.  This is actually a good thing as you can programmatically set these for the client connection rather than having it use the global.  In order to do this, you need to create a ClientBuilder and set the hostname verifier and sslcontext to something you control.

```
public Client buildUnsecureRestClient() throws GeneralSecurityException {
  SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
  TrustManager[] trustManagerArray = {
      ...
  };
  context.init(myKeyManagers, trustManagerArray, new SecureRandom());
  return ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
    .hostnameVerifier(myhostnameverifier)
    .sslContext(context)
    .build();
```

}

By setting the SSLContext to contain your own key manager which you can build programmatically.  I have a sample where I used the techique to [bypass the SSL certificate checks for JAX-RS](http://www.trajano.net/2015/02/ssl-certificate-bypass-for-jax-rs/), but you can implement the X509KeyManager to provide your keys.  The X509TrustManager is a bit tricker to deal with, and I would recommend you use the one that comes with your target JDK even if it will lock you to Oracle's which is `sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl`, but since this is WebStart chances are the JRE you are using is from Oracle rather than IBM JREs.

Comment: Not sure if it was clear from the description but I already know this - and it's a horrible solution. Application developers shouldn't be implementing essential security components like trust managers.

What I need is a way to use the existing user-managed trust store in the Java Control Panel. If the user has decided he trusts a CA certificate, my app should be able to honour that. Building a custom trust manager for my app is all kinds of wrong.